# How to find the cause for delay in Elastic Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cloud, filebeat

We have a cluster on Elastic cloud that we use to ingest logs from docker on an instance in AWS. We use filebeat to collect the logs of all containers on the instance and an ingest pipeline to parse the log and add fields.

Recently, we noticed a 2h delay on one of the containers logs. The log is still ingested since we can see new data added to the index from time to time. The weird part is that all other containers logs are in real time. There are no errors on filebeat so I guess the bottleneck must be on ES side.

I'd like to identify where the possible bottleneck is and I don't know how.

Comment: If you have more than one container and only one of them has delay it can be because of the `timestamp` field. Can you check the date of the containers with `date` command?

Comment: I've check both the delayed container and a not delayed one and they have the same date

Comment: Can you see any error or exception on elasticsearch logs? eg `mapping_conflict`.

Comment: I don't see anything in the logs. I've set up my ingest pipelines to add the ingest time field `_ingest.timestamp` to see the lag. Since `@timestamp` is set to the time filebeat sent the log and that there is a difference between the two fields, I guess the bottleneck happens before the indexing request

Comment: nice catch! If you are making sure that the logs are populating frequently, enabling the debug log on filebeat can help you.